# Exposing managed events to COM using C++

Tags: c#, c++, events, com, atl

It is possible to exposed managed events written in C# to be exposed and used in a COM object written using c++. not being that familiar with com and atl. Can you please show what would the C++ side of things would look like for the example shown in the MSDN article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3.aspx

The VB6 code shown proves that it is doable.

Comment: What technology are you using on unmanaged side, ATL, MFC or something else?

Comment: I guess any will do as long as the job gets done. I would prefer towards the solution that is simple and concise.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way in C++ would be, IMO, to implement an event sink with help of ATL's `IDispEventImpl` and `IDispEventSimpleImpl` templates. An explanation with sample project [can be found here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194179).

There are many online resources about how to do this, e.g. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b91kf2t0(v=vs.71).aspx) or [this](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/arcgisdevhelp/developmentenvs/com/vcpp/events.htm), but here is the list of required steps:

First let's take a look at managed side.

In order to provide events, we must do the following:

- declare an event interface (`IDispatch`-based)
- mark the coclass with `ComSourceInterfaces` attribute to bind the event interface to coclass
- implement matching events in the coclass

Here are is the managed code:

```
[ComVisible(true), 
 Guid("D6D3565F-..."), 
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)] //! must be IDispatch
public interface IMyEvents
{
    [DispId(1)] // the dispid is used to correctly map the events
    void SomethingHappened(DateTime timestamp, string message);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("E22E64F7-...")]
[ProgId("...")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyEvents))] // binding the event interface
public class MyComServer : IMyComServer  
{
    // here we declare the delegate for the event
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(DateTime timestamp, string message);

    // and a public event which matches the method in IMyEvents
    // your code will raise this event when needed
    public event MyEventHandler SomethingHappened;
    ... 
}
```

Now, back to unmanaged side. I will use ATL, as I find it the most effective way to write COM clients, but you can try MFC or do it 'manually'.

The following steps are required:

- the sink will inherit `IDispEventSimpleImpl` (or `IDispEventImpl`)
- sink map with all the needed methods is declared
- handler methods are written for each event
- the sink is registered with event source
- eventually, when not needed anymore, the sink is disconnected

Here's the code in an ATL C++ client:

```
// import the typelib of your COM server
// 'named_guids' ensures friendly ID of event interface
#import "myserver.tlb" named_guids 
const UINT SINK_ID = 234231341; // we need some sink id

class MyClient : public IDispEventSimpleImpl<SINK_ID, MyClient, &MyServer::DIID_IMyEvents >
{
    public:
    // now you need to declare a sink map - a map of methods handling the events
    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(MyClient)
      SINK_ENTRY_INFO(SINK_ID, MyServer::DIID_IMyEvents, 0x1, OnSomethingHappened, &someEvent)
                                                   ^      ^      ^                   ^
      // event interface id (can be more than 1)---+      |      |                   |
      // must match dispid of your event -----------------+      |                   |
      // method which handles the event  ------------------------+                   |
      // type information for event, see below --------------------------------------+
    END_SINK_MAP()

// declare the type info object. You will need one for each method with different signature.
// it will be defined in the .cpp file, as it is a static member
static _ATL_FUNC_INFO someEvent;  // 'placeholder' object to carry event information (see below)

// method which handles the event
STDMETHOD (OnSomethingHappened)(DATE timestamp, BSTR message)
{ 
   // usually it is defined it in the .cpp file
}

...
```

}

Now, we need to define the type info members in the cpp file (i.e. the `someEvent` instance from example above):

```
_ATL_FUNC_INFO MyClient::traceEvent = { CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2 , {VT_DECIMAL, VT_BSTR} };  // dispid = 1
                                               ^        ^     ^              ^
// calling convention (always stdcall) --------+        |     |              |
// type of return value (only VT_EMPTY makes sense) ----+     |              |
// number of parameters to the event -------------------------+              |
// Variant types of event arguments -----------------------------------------+
```

This can be tricky as type mappings are not always obvious (e.g. a it might be clear that managed `int` maps to `VT_I4`, but it is less obvious that `DateTime` maps to `VT_DECIMAL`).
You need to declare each event you plan to use in the sink map - if you don't need all of them, don't map them.

Now you need to connect your sink to the event source:

```
// IUnknown* pUnk = interface to you COM server instance
pMyClient->DispEventAdvise(pUnk);
// .. from this point, events will be caught by the client
// when you are done, disconnect:
pMyClient->DispEventUnadvise(pUnk);
```

This is it, more or less. Using  `IDispEventImpl` instead of `IDispEventSimpleImpl` results in a bit less code, as you don't need to supply the type info objects which might be the ugliest part. However, it has two drawbacks:

- requires access to the typelib (as it needs to read the interface metadata in order to provide the type info itself)
- is a bit slower (but I would guess not significantly)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++/CLI you can just do ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

```
// class that defines methods that will called when event occurs
ref class EventReceiver {
public:
   void OnMyClick(int i, double d) {
      Console::WriteLine("OnClick: {0}, {1}", i, d);
   }

   void OnMyDblClick(String^ str) {
      Console::WriteLine("OnDblClick: {0}", str);
   }
};

int main() {
   EventSource ^ MyEventSource = gcnew EventSource();
   EventReceiver^ MyEventReceiver = gcnew EventReceiver();

   // hook handler to event
   MyEventSource->OnClick += gcnew ClickEventHandler(MyEventReceiver, &EventReceiver::OnMyClick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Zdeslav Vojkovic was almost the complete answer for me, however I ran into stability issues, when implementing the sink in an Outlook add-in. After the first unadvise the system became unstable and could crash at the next advise. The solution for me was to make the sink as a COM object.

For brevity I have only added the ATL side of the solution, as the managed code can be left exactly as Zdeslav Vojkovic proposed.

I followed these steps in Visual Studio 2017:

### Create ATL Simple Object

1. Right-click on Project and select Add > New Item...
2. Select ATL Simple Object and click the Add button
3. In the Other tab select "Single" for Threading model
4. Click Finish

### Fill in the sink interface details

In the generated idl add handlers for initialization and shutdown:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(a5211fba-...),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyClient : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method InitHandler"), local] HRESULT InitHandler(IUnknown* myserver);
    [id(2), helpstring("method ShutdownHandler"), local] HRESULT ShutdownHandler(void); 
};
```

### Fill in the header file (MyClient.h)

```
const UINT SINK_ID = 234231341;
extern _ATL_FUNC_INFO SomethingHappenedInfo;

// LIBID_MyATLComLib should point to the LIBID of the type library 
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyClient :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CMyClient, &CLSID_MyClient>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IMyClient, &IID_IMyClient, &LIBID_MyATLComLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IDispEventSimpleImpl<SINK_ID, CMyClient, &MyServer::DIID_IMyEvents>
{
public:

    typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl</*nID =*/ SINK_ID, CMyClient, &MyServer::DIID_IMyEvents> SomethingHappenedEvent;

    ...

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CMyClient)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(SINK_ID, MyServer::DIID_IMyEvents, 0x1, OnSomethingHappened, &SomethingHappenedInfo)
    END_SINK_MAP()

    ...

private:
    CComQIPtr<MyServer::IMyComServer> mMyComServer; 

public:    
    STDMETHOD(InitHandler)(IUnknown* myserver);
    STDMETHOD(ShutdownHandler)(void);

    void __stdcall OnSomethingHappened(DateTime timestamp, string message);     
};
```

Some of the generated code has been left as "..."

### Fill in the C++ code (MyClient.cpp)

```
_ATL_FUNC_INFO SomethingHappenedInfo = { CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2 , {VT_DECIMAL, VT_BSTR} };


STDMETHODIMP CMyClient::InitHandler(IUnknown* myserver)
{
    this->mMyComServer = myserver;
    SomethingHappenedEvent::DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)this->mMyComServer);

    return S_OK;
}


STDMETHODIMP CMyClient::ShutdownHandler(void)
{    
    SomethingHappenedEvent::DispEventUnadvise(this->mMyComServer);          

    return S_OK;
}

void __stdcall CMyClient::OnSomethingHappened(DateTime timestamp, string message)
{   
    ...
}
```

Notice that the Advise/Unadvise calls are done differently here.